# Arduino killed trying to load a sketch?

Tags: arduino, avr

I'm trying to build RGB led color picker from ladyada.net tutorials.
http://www.ladyada.net/make/eshield/examples.html

I build ethernet shield, installed on my Arduino Duemilanove with ATMEGA328 and then load the sketch from ladyada web site.
http://www.ladyada.net/make/eshield/LEDcolorpicker.pde

This code dosent's work for me, until I break line into two separate and re-merge at runtime.
I need to remove some piece of code to make it works.

After burning 3 times this sketch on my Arduino, it seems not to responde anymore.
On extensive log I see:

```
     avrdude: Version 5.4-arduino, compiled on Oct  9 2007 at 11:20:31
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

     System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/Users/emaaaa/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

     Using Port            : /dev/tty.usbserial-A9007MIy
     Using Programmer      : stk500v1
     Overriding Baud Rate  : 115200
     avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
     avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
     avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
     avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: Send: Q [51]   [20] 
     avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Anyone have some ideas ?
I tryed on 2 different arduino 2009, same results

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const char javascript[] PROGMEM = "..."` is a >5,000 character string.  It's possible that the Arduino IDE doesn't support line lengths of this size, you can break it up using the continuation character `\` at the end of your line:

```
const char javascript[] PROGMEM = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function" \
" getScrollY(){var scrOfX = 0,scrOfY=0;if(typeof(window.pageYOffset)=='number')" \
"{scrOfY=window.pageYOffset;scrOfX=window.pageXOffset;}else if(document.body&&" \
[Many more lines]
"setCCbldSty2('colorpicker201','ds','block');" \
"document.getElementById('colorpicker201').innerHTML=mid;}</script>";
```

Note that you can't have // comments at the end of these lines.

If this is what you meant by "broke into 2 parts" you should be fine.  Otherwise, I think your reassembly at runtime is suspicious.

Comment: I will try to upload this sketch as soon I restore my Arudino. I'm not able to upload nothing to IT after i upload the ledpitcher sketch. It continuosly blink the mini led and report error top of this page message

Answer (score 1):

I know after awhile on my arduino that i had to start pressing the reset button before sending the sketch, this may help. Next try just using a simple LED blinky sketch(can be found in the examples on the IDE) If it works your arduino is fine.

as for the other sketch I don't understand what you mean by this

> This code [does not] work for me, until I break line into two separate and re-merge at runtime. I need to remove some piece of code to make it works.

can you explain that a little better?

Comment: Thank jsolarski ;) I press the reset butotn on arudino but nothing change, even if I try to upload blinking led sketch nothing happen. Some strange behaviour on Arudino is the mini-led soldierd onboard is blinking continuosly a high frequncy. <br> In led picker sketch at line 25 there's a "const char javascript[] PROGMEM = ", If i leave this as is Arudino IDE dosen't allow me to build. If i broke into 2 parts it run.